# How to do http calls clean in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm writing a protractor test for an angularJS app.
But because there is a lot of setup, I use a beforeAll section to do a lot of http calls directly to backend, so objects are created and data is created.
Though I struggle on how to write this in a clean, comprehensive way, using protractor.

For the moment I'm using `flow.execute()` to keep all the calls in order.
Most of them have to be called one after the other, so I just can't put all the asynchronous calls in the beforeAll and hope for the best.

For example:

I first create object A through *objectService.create('A')*, which will do a HTTP POST and returns me the created object. Then I create a collection through *collectionService.create('someCollection')*, which also is an async callto backend. Afterwards I put the returned object A in the created collection through *collectionService.add(objectA)*.

This is only a simple example, but in my case there are multiple calls and much more actions.

For this example I would have the following code:

```
describe('Some example test', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        flow.execute(() => {
            objectService.create('A');
        });
        flow.execute(() => {
            collectionService.create();
        });
        flow.execute(() => {
            collectionService.add(objectA);
        });
        // Possible more of these async calls that need to be sequentially executed
    });

    it('test', () => {
        // Here comes the protractor test
    });
});
```

Now my  question is, how can I get rid of the `flow.execute()` and still do all the async calls in the correct order in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the controlFlow to make sure they get populated in the right order. But you might be able to do some things with your other asynchronous calls to group them:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    flow.execute(() => {
        return Promise.all([
            objectService.create('A');
            collectionService.create('someCollection');
        ]).then(function([object, collection]) {
            return collection.add(object);
        }).then(function() {
            // Possible more of these async calls that need to be sequentially executed
        });
    });
});
```

And of course this can be wrapped up neatly into some helper function that you tuck away somewhere if you think it's ugly to look at in the test ;)

```
var addObjectToCollection(objectName, collectionName) {
    return browser.controlFlow().execute(() => {
        return Promise.all([
            objectService.create(objectName);
            collectionService.create(collectionName);
        ]).then(([object, collection]) => {
            return collection.add(object);
        });
    });
};


beforeAll(() => {
    addObjectToCollection('objectA', 'collection1');
    // some expectation will show you that this does indeed execute in the right order
    expect(element(by.css('.object-count')).getText()).toBe('1');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll look into your approach. Though I definetly want to hide the `flow.execute()` part. As for now I wrapped it around every function seperatly, but a helper function here could come in handy.